# How to write a function that writes both to console and log file?

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to write a function that writes a message both to console and log file. My initial attempt was this one:

```
function log_write {
    local message=$1
    local log_file=$2
    echo "${message}" | tee -a ${log_file}
}
```

But that doesn't work - I guess because echo in a function context means 'return a value', not write to console. What did I miss? I invoke it like this in my script:

```
message='something interesting happened'
log_file='my_script.log'
$(log_write $message $log_file)
```

Also, I run it on Windows via msysgit port, but I double that's the problem.

Comment: looks good to me. `echo` in a function context is exactly the same as `echo` in a command-line context: print stuff to your terminal. What precisely "didn't work"? Exactly how do you invoke the function?

Comment: @glennjackman edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Substitution) syntax is the problem here:

```
$(log_write $message $log_file)
```

That invokes the function, and **returns** the output, ready to be captured in a variable. However, you're not doing that.

Instead you want to invoke your function just like any other command:

```
log_write "$message" "$log_file"
```

Note the quotes: they are crucial to keep multi-word messages as a single argument. Otherwise, if you do this:

```
message="hello world"
log_write $message $log_file
```

Then, you'll get the word "hello" written to the file "world". This happens due to [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) after the variable is expanded. Rule of thumb: **always** quote your variables, except when you explicitly want the word splitting and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion) effects of omitting the quotes. There are also [security implications in omitting quotes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667)

Comment: oh, I see. that must be it. I'll try it out, thanks